# Google API compatibility issue

Tags: android

I try to replicate the Google Drive QuickStart example
but when I try to debug on my device (4.0.4) an exclamation point (!)
appears next to 4.0.4 under the Target field on the Android Device Choose Dialog
What does this mean, do I need to configure my device? and how?